# Get user email address client side

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, csom, ie

I am using the following code (below) in a IE 11 browser on SharePoint 2013 on premises to successfully to return the user and email address - however I am unable to get the email to pass to a variable to use for a later third party script.

Please can someone advise how pass the email out to a variable - All the usual methods leave the variable undefined?

```
var clientContext;
var user;

// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your
// code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

    clientContext.load(user);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('The email address of the current user is ' + user.get_email());
    alert('The account name is ' + user.get_loginName());
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: THis code was lifted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245596.aspx

Comment: Have you checked what is in the global ``_spPageContextInfo``....

Comment: Ok my bad - I now appreciate the call was asynchronous and for my subsequent code to run correctly it needed to be moved into the onQuerySucceeded. Once I did this the email address was resolved and available for the next part of my script. I have marked Dmitry as correct as he had correctly diagnosed this in the second part of his response. (Thanks Dmitry). Thanks everyone for help Craig ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it just email that is null? If so, it might be unset/unavailable.

Is it possible, that you access `user` variable before it initialized?

`sharePointReady`, and `onQuerySucceeded` are async. Probably you should add you code in the end of `onQuerySucceeded`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Yes the async is the problem in this case. I have script running after and it runs before the onQuerySucceeded has run and set the variable for the user email address. Trying to see if I can include the third party script with in the success module and then have it run once the variable set correctly. Will mark correct once i prove this in code.

Comment: You should try to use promises/ defferds to fix this issue.